# Is the load-on-startup tag in web.xml mandatory?

Tags: spring, web.xml

Is the `load-on-startup` tag a mandatory tag in web.xml to load dispatcher servlet in spring?  Will our dispatcher servlet get initialized if it doesn't mention this tag?

Answer (score 0):

**yes** it's required, *if* you expect to dispatch or render anything using spring.

Comment: what happens if i give load value some positive value, other than 1, say 3 or 4, and we have only single servlet, In our case its dispatcher servlet.

Comment: @arun depends on app server. I think any non-zero is true. But you could try it.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not mandatory. If you do not specify "load-on-startup" tag, your project will still work fine, except for the fact that the servlet will take slightly more time to load for the first request. This tag is helpful if you have multiple servlets and you want to control the loading flow. If you have multiple servlets, then the servlet which has the least "load-on-startup" value will be loaded first.

In the below example, `servlet1` will be loaded first, then `servlet2` will be loaded, and so on.

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>X</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet>
<servlet-name>servlet2</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Y</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```